# how to create a function (number: Int), which accepts the parameter num as a number, then print numbers from 1 to num with the following conditions:

Tags: kotlin

how to create a function (number: Int), which accepts the parameter num as a number,
then print numbers from 1 to num with the following conditions:

- if the number can be divided by 3, then print a letter
- if the number can be divided by 5, then print the word
- if the numbers can be divided 3 & 5, then print a letterword

Example output:
letterword (5)
1
2
letter
4
word

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Note that Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You're expected to [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/5698098). Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about what's [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and read [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). If you get stuck somewhere then it's a good idea to ***ask a specific question*** here based on your own solution attempt; providing a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

*Not sure what you mean by print 'the word'. Is there a specific word or letter?*
*For the conditions you can definitely use [when](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html), one of the Kotlin flow control operators and the **Modulus(%)** operator to check if number can be divided by the 3 or 5 or both*

```
fun numberConditions(number : Int){
        when{
            //[number] can be divided by 3 and 5
            number % 3 == 0 && number % 5 == 0 -> {
                println("LetterWord")
            }`enter code here`
    
            //[number] can be divided by 3
            number % 3 == 0 -> {
                println("Letter")
            }
    
            //[number] can be divided by 5
            number % 5 == 0 -> {
                println("Word")
            }
    
            // [number] cannot be divided by 3 and 5
            else -> {
                println("number does not satisfy any of the conditions")
            }
        }
    }
```